# Flutter multi row display with padding in card?

Tags: flutter, web, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I want to find the best way to draw multiple  rows in flutter card

[image]

Comment: you should add this answer as a comment on your post or add it to your on post

Answer (score 1):

Try To below code hope it help you:

```
Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0))),
        elevation: 2,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: ExpansionTile(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            title: Text('ok'),
            trailing: SizedBox(),
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(Icons.person),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    Text("ABC"),
                   
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Divider(),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(Icons.check),
                    SizedBox(width: 10,),
                    Text("Bike"),
                    
                    
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Your Screen Like -> [image]